# Get specific data from XML document

Tags: c#, xml

I have xml document like this:

```
<level1>
 <level2>
  <level3>
   <attribute1>...</attribute1>
   <attribute2>false</attribute2>
   <attribute3>...</attribute3>
  </level3>
  <level3>
   <attribute1>...</attribute1>
   <attribute2>true</attribute2>
   <attribute3>...</attribute3>
  </level3>
</level2>
<level2>
 <level3>
   <attribute1>...</attribute1>
   <attribute2>false</attribute2>
...
...
...
```

I'm using c#, and I want to go thru all "level3", and for every "level3", i want to read attribute2, and if it says "true", i want to print the corresponding attribute3 (can be "level3" without these attributes).

I keep the xml in XmlDocument.
Then I keep all the "level3" nodes like this:

```
XmlNodeList xnList = document.SelectNodes(String.Format("/level1/level2/level3"));
```

(document is the XmlDocument).

But from now on, I don't know exactly how to continue. I tried going thru xnList with for..each, but nothing works fine for me..

How can I do it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I would do what Jon Skeet suggested, but I would suggest another change.  I would say if attribute1 through attribute3 are actually attributes of level3 then why don't you make them attributes of the level3 node?

Answer (score 4):

Well I'd use LINQ to XML:

```
var results = from level3 in doc.Descendants("level3")
              where (bool) level3.Element("attribute2")
              select level3.Element("attribute3").Value;

foreach (string result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

LINQ to XML makes all kinds of things *much* simpler than the `XmlDocument` API. Of course, the downside is that it requires .NET 3.5...

(By the way, naming *elements* `attributeN` is a bit confusing... one would expect `attribute` to refer to an actual XML attribute...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to XML and reading [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) is a good start.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an XPath query. This will give you a `XmlNodeList` that contains all `<attribute3>` elements that match your requirement:

```
var list = document.SelectNodes("//level3[attribute2 = 'true']/attribute3");

foreach(XmlNode node in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
}
```

You can split the above xpath query in three parts:

1. "`//level3`" queries for all descendant elements named `<level3>`.
2. "`[attribute2 = 'true']`" filters the result from `(1)` and only keeps the elements where the child element `<attribute2>` contains the text `true`.
3. "`/attribute3`" takes the `<attribute3>` childnode of each element in the result of `(2)`.

Comment: Thanks! if attribute 2 can be true/false/somethingelse, and i want to get all the cases except true, how do i write [attribute2 != 'true']...?

Comment: @user64140 : You could write both `[attribute2 != 'true']` or `not(attribute2 = 'true')`